# Why Addthis share button is not working without server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, share, addthis

Here is my Code of [Addthis](http://www.addthis.com/):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="addthis_widget.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var addthis_config = {
           services_expanded: 'facebook, twitter'
 }
 </script>

 <a addthis:services_compact="facebook,twitter" addthis:services_expanded="facebook,twitter" addthis:url="#" class="addthis_button" href="#"><img id="btn_share" name="btn_share" style="cursor:pointer;" src="path to image" alt="Share" /></a>
```

If I put this [Addthis](http://www.addthis.com/) code in simple HTML file and try to run through any server for example in my case I'm using Apache. And try to run from the browser through localhost/myaddthis.html, than its work fine (show the proper popup to share specific link to facebook and twitter).

But the problem is: when I try to run simple html file direct inside browser, then its just show the image, don't show the proper addthis share popup.

It's just a simple .HTML file (there is no server side code inside the file), than why its not running without server.

I want to use this code without server. How I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably viewing your pages by opening them as local files rather than loading them from a web server. So instead of the URL of the page in your browser starting with http:// it starts with C:\ or file://

Here's what the AddThis buttons look like when viewed via http:// - https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdiiV.png

And here's the same file viewed using file:// - https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7re9.png

We currently are using protocol-free URLs in our code - ones that start with // instead of http:// or https:// - to make sure our SSL implementations are cross compatible without extra work. However, if you're loading the test page with the file:// protocol it causes the CSS and other JavaScript files not to load, since it's looking for them on your local machine rather than our web servers.

I've submitted a ticket to our developers to fix this for people previewing pages using their file system rather than a web server, but until they can get that implemented you should either understand that the buttons won't show up if using the file:// protocol or use a web server in order to test how your sites display in browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's normal since AddThis is to share stuff on social websites.
If you're not on a server, you won't be able to share stuff because it's a local file.

It's probably inside the addThis code to check for the server. If it's not a server then it doesn't have to share.

This is common sense if you ask me but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Addthis will check for the current url - `http://localhost/etc.` is a valid location, but `file://path/to/yourfile.html` is not.